# How does Python process one-hot-encoded data?

Tags: python

When I use Python sci-kit learn for Machine Learning project I often use one-hot-encoding.
My X dataset consists of rows like this: [1,2,[1,0] ].where the third entry ([1,0]) comes from one-hot-encoding.

Is this equivalent to using a data set where the rows are like [1,2,1,0]?

(I.e. where the rows have been 'flattened')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual values of the one-hot-encoded vector can be flattened as individual features. There is a special function in pandas to perform this [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).